# Any ideas on how to refresh this Captcha type?

Tags: javascript

I want to refresh Captcha image without refreshing page nor exsiting , through a javascript code .
 I tried to use the `Date.now()` method , as a result the captcha image is refreshing to an image that says NOCODE .

**The Url that i'll provide is only  for example porposes :**

Url : https://www.gametwist.com/web/Register

already used code :

```
 document.querySelector('.captcha').src += '&_=' + Date.now();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ReCaptcha, there is already a function `grecaptcha.reset` for that in the javascript [API](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display)

Else, then please specify what you are using.

**Edit** : Since you are not using ReCaptcha and don't have access to JQuery, then what I suggest is to use the `getElementById()` function to access the element, then use the `innerHTML` property to reset it contents.

For those who have access to JQuery, you could simply use

```
$('#thisdiv').load(document.URL +  ' #thisdiv');
```

To refresh part of page. Credit to user1721135 for this part.

Comment: savard   honstly i'm not using the captcha thing , i'm programming  a javascript code that fill a form automatically  and i'm encoutered the same captcha type that i demonestrated in the website link , but for a deffirent website . so i don't know what i'm dealing with .

Comment: @Dana10 do you have JQuery or only pure javascript ?

Comment: @Jan-francois only javascript